# Is the PDO Library faster than the native MySQL Functions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have read several questions regarding this but I fear they may be out of date as newer versions of the PDO libraries have been released since these questions were answered.

I have written a MySQL class that builds queries and escapes parameters, and then returns results based on the query. Currently this class is using the built-in mysql functions.

I am well aware of the advantages of using the PDO Library, e.g. it is compatible with other databases, stored procedures are easier to execute etc... **However, what I would like to know is simply; is using the PDO Library faster then using the mysql built-in functions?**

I have just written the equivalent class for MsSQL, so rewriting it to work with all databases would not take me long at all. Is it worth it or is the PDO library slower?

Comment: That is interesting question... I was always using PDO just because of one thing... stored procedures... I haven't checked for speed... but stored procedures are enough for me :P. Stored procedures always increase security of web applications, because if you use them, there is no place for "I forgot `mysql_real_escape_string()` call" :).

Comment: If you're aware of the _many_ other advantages to PDO, but are only concerned about speed, why not just benchmark it and find out if it meets your needs? PDO is superior in so many ways, even if it was a bit slower, it still has the advantage.

Comment: PDO is marginally slower than `mysql` functions. However, what `mysql` extension doesn't have is prepared statements. Therefore, if you have a lengthy insert, using PDO will be much faster via prepared statements because you'll just send parameters to already parsed query. However, speed **should not** be the deciding factor here. You should use PDO instead of `mysql` functions. Also, it's much easier to code with PDO plus it's great to do stuff in 1 line that you'd do in 5 - 10 lines with `mysql` stuff.

Comment: PDO is an abstraction library, it would be normal to be a bit slower (even if the difference is not that big), but you should choose it for its other advantages (named parameters, buffered queries, no need for escaping etc)

Comment: Thanks for all your responses! I would have tested the speed myself but I have not had a chance

Comment: Thanks @MarcusAdams, that is very helpful. By the looks of it, the difference in speed it pretty minimal!

Comment: @MarcusAdams, Could you possibly post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :-)

Comment: @Marcus Adams : PDO doesn't _use_ mysqli, both extensions use the same two driver options: libmysql or mysqlnd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found PDO in many situation/projects to be even faster than the more native modules.
Mainly because many patterns/building blocks in a "PDO-application" require less php script driven code and more code is executed in the compiled extension and there *is* a speed penalty when doing things in the script. Simple, synthetic tests without data and error handling often do not cover this part, which is why (amongst other problems like e.g. measuring inaccuracies) I think "10000x SELECT x FROM foo took 10ms longer" conclusions are missing the point more often than not .
I can't provide you with solid benchmarks and the outcome depends on how the surrounding application handles the data but even synthetic tests usually only show differences so negligible that you better spend your time on optimizing your queries, the MySQL server, the network, ... instead of worrying about PDO's raw performance. Let alone security and error handling ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I am not really bothered by a difference of 10ms, no human will notice this, just as long as it isnt substantially slower, which it seems not to be.

Comment: even if PDO against `mysql_xxxx` functions compare equally or slightly slower, the benefit of using PDO outweighs the "legacy" alternative, IMO

Comment: @BenCarey , if you want to benchmark PDO, you have to remember that when using prepared statements, you are actually not just calling the query but also preventing the injections.

Comment: There's at least one thing PDO still can't do (if I didn't miss it) and that's http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php . But I only needed it once and it was to work around a deeper conceptual flaw...

Comment: @VolkerK That is one of many reasons why I am writing my own class, so it allows you to use both PDO and built-in functions for unsupported PDO queries.

Answer (score 1):

My observation is that PDO seems to be less tolerate of many consecutive connections - that is connections being created in a loop.  I know this is bad practice it the first place.  When I was using mysql_* my looped queries seemed to be reasonably fast. However when I switched to PDO I noticed much longer response times for these types of queries.

TL;DR; - If you switch to PDO and you call queries in a PHP loop you may need to rewrite the application to call one single query rather than many consecutive queries.